# Windows Shared Storage / External SAS3 / JBOD

Tags: windows, direct-attached-storage

I have two Windows 2016 servers which are directly connected to an external JBOD (with non-RAID cards).  Most of the drives are raw and are being used in an Oracle Cluster.  There are a few drives that are not being used.  Is it possible to mount these drives on each of the servers and use OS mirroring?

All of the drives in the JBOD show up in Disk Management on both of the servers. On one of the servers, I created a mirror and mounted it as "C:\test".  Then when I went to the other server, it showed the drives as "Foreign".

Is it possible to create a mirror set and have both servers access it?  I know I could put the drives in a NAS enclosure and accomplish it.  I'd like to do it with the hardware I have onhand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then when I went to the other server, it showed the drives as "Foreign".

This is because NTFS (and ReFS) are not cluster file systems. The is no way to access a volume from two windows machines at the same time. What seems to be very easy when using Objectstorage oder vmWare VMFS actually needs *a lot* of magic under the hood.

> Is it possible to create a mirror set and have both servers access it?

No. Even in a Windows Server Cluster scenario, the drive would failover from one host to the other, instead of beeing used by both machines at the same time.

> I know I could put the drives in a NAS enclosure and accomplish it.

In that case, the drives wouldn't be accessed by a file system driver (like NTFS or ReFS), but by a network protocol (like SMB oder NFS), which is designed to allow multiple access.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I wonder if a 3rd party makes a solution?

Comment: 3rd party ... what?

Comment: Is there another company who specializes in this and makes something which can make an attached / active-active / clustered file system?

Comment: This question is way beyont the scope of SF and depends completely on your goals (and the admin's taste). I personally do love VMFS, but VMFS is not a everyday file store. There are a lot of cluster-enabled FS out there, like XFS and even SMB ...